# Can you pass grep() a vector of patterns?

Tags: r, regex

Is

```
grep(c(pattern1, pattern2, pattern3), ...)
```

valid?

Comment: yes, but not like that

Comment: R is interactive - just try it - `grep(c("a","b","c"),"a bit of character")` and read the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can illustrate with an example. Here are a few state abbreviations by region.

```
south <- c('FL', 'TN', 'LA', 'GA')
west <- c('CA', 'NV', 'WA', 'AZ')
```

Let's look for southern states with 'A' or 'L' in their abbreviations.

```
y1 <- 'A'
y2 <- 'L'
```

We could have just written them in to the `grep` function and separated them with a pipe character `|`. Or we could practice using variable names. We don't get the correct output if the variables are concatenated.

```
grep('A|L', south, value=TRUE)
[1] "FL" "LA" "GA"

grep(paste(y1, y2, sep='|'), south, value=TRUE)
[1] "FL" "LA" "GA"

grep(c(y1, y2), south, value=TRUE)
[1] "LA" "GA"
Warning message:
In grep(c(y1, y2), south, value = TRUE) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

But there's even more. What if we wanted to find the southern states that have `'L'`, and western states that have `'A'`? We would have to write two functions, right?

```
mapply(grep, list(y2, y1), list(south, west), value=TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "FL" "LA"

[[2]]
[1] "CA" "WA" "AZ"
```

All done in one step.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. But you can always vectorize a function quickly by using `Vectorize` (but sometimes the performance is not that great).

Without vectorizing:

```
grep(list("x1", "x2"), list("x1","x2")) # does not work
[1] 1
Warning message:
In grep(list("x1", "x2"), list("x1", "x2")) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Vectorizing:

```
Vectorize(grep)(list("x1", "x2"), list("x1","x2")) # it works
[1] 1 1
```

Or, if you want, you can vectorize only specific arguments:

```
Vectorize(grep, "pattern" )(c("a","b","c"),c("aa","bb","cc","aa2"))
$a
[1] 1 4

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3
```

If you are going to use the vectorized version a lot, maybe you should assign them to other functions:

```
vgrep <- Vectorize(grep)
vgrep(list("x1", "x2"), list("x1","x2"))
[1] 1 1
```

Comment: `lapply` / `sapply` would be safer - e.g. - `lapply(c("a","b","c"),grep,x=c("aa","bb","cc","aa2"))` vs. `Vectorize(grep)(c("a","b","c"),c("aa","bb","cc","aa2"))`

Comment: @thelatemail `Vectorize` vectorized both arguments (it is a `mapply` on `pattern` and `x`), so the result is actually what we would expect. To get the same result as your `lapply` one should vectorize only the `pattern` like `Vectorize(grep, "pattern" )(c("a","b","c"),c("aa","bb","cc","aa2"))`.